# Recoding Area labels based on zip code data in excel

Tags: spss, recode

Basically, I'm using SPSS and have a variable named AREA that includes different major counties in California. Within this variable there is a value label for "Other" and I want to be able to relabel the data to go in their respective county. I have an excel sheet with all the zip codes that fall into those "Other" counties and do have a zip code data in the file as well. There are 400+ zip codes so I'm trying to see if there is an easy alternative to having to manually type in each zipcode into syntax to recode those values.

I've tried seeing if there was a way to reference the excel workbook, but have come up empty handed.

Any guidance or approaches to this problem would be appreciated!

The data in excel has unique zipcodes with corresponding Area value in cell to the right. In the data set there may be multiple instances of each zipcode.

[image: Excel data format]

Comment: How is the Excel with the ZIP code info structured?  Is there one row per zip code, or one row per county?

Comment: One row per zip with each column being a county.

Comment: read the excel file into SPSS and save it as a `.sav` file, then use `match files` ([see nice tutorial](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-match-files-command/)) to add the data from the excel to your main data - matched by zipcode.

Comment: So I'm still experiencing issues with this not mapping out to all the zipcodes I have in the original file. For example I have 1500 values in the original AREA "other" value label and when I do the match from excel it is only relabeling 350 of them. I went through the dataset and found that there were plenty of zipcodes that were in the excel data that are showing up as missing. I'm doing a one-many merge using add variables through GUI.